# Multidimensional Array: Set the value of an item in it to another one

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I have two two-dimensional arrays, and this line of code:

```
openListParents[compWith] = openList[olID];
```

Does it work? Yes. However, openListParents[compWith] becomes openList[olID], but I want openListParents[compWith] to be the **value** of openList[olID]. This is what I get when I press CTRL+ALT+V:

```
Variable _level0.openListParents = [object #13, class 'Array'] [
0:[object #14, class 'Array'] [
  0:4,
  1:4
],
1:[object #7, class 'Array'],
2:[object #15, class 'Array'] [
  0:3,
  1:3
]
```

]

This is because openList might change, and I want the value of that openListParents in the array to be the value of the openList at the time when the code is run.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is it is being passed by reference. 
what you want is a copy of the array not a reference to the array.

a quick way to do that in AS3 is to do an empty concat on the array and it will return a copy of itself with nothing added

```
array2 = array1.concat()
//array2 now has a copy of array1
```

Comment: Ok, but I don't want to copy the whole array. I only want to copy 1 element out of the array.

Comment: oh I thought the values inside the arrays were another array since you mentioned that it was a 2-dimensional array. Did I misunderstand?

Comment: Yes the values inside the array were another array, sorry I should have thought array1[2].concat() I'll test to see if it works